# Unable to login as superuser in Django admin (Django Girls Tutorial)

Tags: python, django

I have created a app in `python 3.5` and `django 1.8.5`on WIndows 7(32bit).
I have create new user in my app but have some problem with login.

When I logged in with newly created superuser then this error message is shown:

```
>>Error:- Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.
```

I followed the [Django Girls Tutorial](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/index.html#django-girls-tutorial) and everything worked fine till I reached the [Django Admin](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_admin/index.html) part.

The tutorial asks the reader to start the server *then* create the superuser. I did it the other way round: created the super-user (admin) *then* started the server (does this make a difference?). Navigated to http://localhost:8000/admin and tried to log in.

The login didn't work. Then, while the server was running, I first created one super-user (gaurav) and then another (sharma) and neither one worked. All three super-users had the same password.

Please someone help me to solve this issue. :)

Comment: Try making new superuser using `python manage.py createsuperuser`, and check if you are able to login through this newly created user ?

Comment: @skbly7 I updated my description to show that I created three different super-users, but none of them work.

Comment: Have you made migrations and ran them. "python manage.py makemigrations" and then "migrate" so that the db is populated with everything you have created so far?

Comment: @pycode333 Yes exactly, I have already done with your commands but still getting this error.

Comment: Please check the DB, That user is created or not ?
Also change the password of that users and try again to login.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've done this, in which case ignore my answer. But you didn't mention migrations. Your problem would be solved by manage.py migrations then manage.py migrate -- as the superuser needs to be stuck into the database first. It doesn't matter whether the server is running first or second. (You will however run into problems if adding the superuser WHILE the server is running on a localhost environment.)